# CSS grid fit column width in one row

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I have a two row grid with three columns. Each row has a text in the middle column. The first row's middle column needs to fit to the text. But when there is a longer text in the second row, the first row's middle column won't fit to the text. A better explanation with pictures above:

[image]

When the first row's text is longer then it fits correctly.

[image]

But when the second row's text is longer than the first row's text, the first row's column won't fit the text.
How can I fit the first row middle column's width to the text?

Here is

```css
html,
body,
.grid-container {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  justify-content: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10vmin min-content 10vmin;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas: "left middle right ""left first-text-middle right""second-text-left second-text-middle second-text-right";
}

.left {
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-area: left;
  text-align: right;
}

.right {
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-area: right;
}

.middle {
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-area: middle;
}

.second-text-left {
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-area: second-text-left;
}

.second-text-right {
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-area: second-text-right;
}

.first-text-middle {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  grid-area: first-text-middle;
  align-self: stretch;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.second-text-middle {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  grid-area: second-text-middle;
  align-self: stretch;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="first-text-middle">
    <span id="n1">LoremIps</span>
  </div>
  <div class="second-text-left "></div>
  <div class="second-text-middle">
    <span id="n3">Lorem</span>
  </div>
  <div class="second-text-right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's not clear at all what you want ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the top text to expand according to the width of the parent element (which has been expanded by the `.second-text-middle` inner text), you could use simple JavaScript.

Here we can check the width of `#n1` and `.first-text-middle`, and increase the `font size: n%;` of `#n1` until it fits the parent.

```js
fitWidth(); 

window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  fitWidth();  
});

function fitWidth() {
  let first = document.querySelector('.first-text-middle');
  let firstText = document.getElementById('n1');
  let textSize = 100; // we will use it like a base 100% font-size later
  
  // set font size to '#n1'  
  firstText.style.cssText = 'font-size:' + textSize + '%';

  while (first.clientWidth - 2 >= firstText.offsetWidth) {
    textSize = textSize + 1; //increments font size by 1% each loop
    firstText.style.cssText = 'font-size:' + textSize + '%';
    // basically in DOM you see only result of the very last loop of this 'while' statment    
  }

}
```

```css
html,
body,
.grid-container {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  justify-content: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10vmin min-content 10vmin;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas: "left middle right ""left first-text-middle right""second-text-left second-text-middle second-text-right";
}

.left {
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-area: left;
  text-align: right;
}

.right {
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-area: right;
}

.middle {
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-area: middle;
}

.second-text-left {
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-area: second-text-left;
}

.second-text-right {
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-area: second-text-right;
}

.first-text-middle {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  grid-area: first-text-middle;
  align-self: stretch;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.second-text-middle {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  grid-area: second-text-middle;
  align-self: stretch;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="first-text-middle">
    <span id="n1">Lorem</span>
  </div>
  <div class="second-text-left "></div>
  <div class="second-text-middle">
    <span id="n3">LoremIps</span>
  </div>
  <div class="second-text-right"></div>
</div>
```